# Поиск наибольшей строки в файле

Tags: строки, perl

Изучаю raku, язык очень нравится, но уже сейчас есть камни преткновения. На данный момент нужно решить  простую задачку, найти самую длинную строку в файле. Как это можно сделать в raku? Синтаксис чем-то напоминает привычный perl. В последнем делаю так: `perl -e 'print((sort{length$a<=>length$b}<>)[-1])' my.txt`

Comment: В Perl я бы сделал так:


`$ perl -nlE 'if($. == 1 or length $_ > length $max) { $max = $_ }  }{ say $max' test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю как-то так:

```
raku -e 'lines.sort({$^b.chars cmp $^a.chars})[0].say' my.txt
```

Синтаксис чем-то ведь действительно схож.